# using ParsleyJS in Rails form_for helper fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, form-for, parsley.js

I am trying to use Parsley in my forms generated through Rails' form_for helper.  The issue is that many of Parsely's HTML options are in this form: `data-type="email"` while for form_for helper uses hashes to generate these HTML options.  My code:

```
<%= form_for [@owner, @restaurant], html: {:"data-validate" => 'parsley'} do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :zip_code, placeholder: "zipcode", :'data-type' => "digits" %>
<%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

How can I use the data-type option that Parsley provides in the form_for rails method?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data attributes are frequently used so they are set to be used out of :html hash.

To set data attributes, use `data` option

```
form_for [@owner, @restaurant], data: {validate: 'parsley'} do |f|
```

This will generate `data-validate='parsley'` in the output form tag.